# can i use aws or cloud computing to build a website building platform like webs.com or blogspot.com?

Tags: php, hosting, amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting

I have a web app running on php and mysql.

i have tested on my localhost and i know it works.

if my platform has a url like myplatform.com, and users sign up, they automatically get a website like user1.myplatform.com or user2.myplatform.com, etc.

Akin to blogger, wordpress or webs.com

now if user1 decides to purchase a url from a domain registrar and gets a myurl.com, there is no problem to do that.

now i am using a webhosting dedicated server solution. apparently there is a problem to use shared hosting. Don't quite get why. If an explanation is given, i will be glad to hear it.

now the key question is I am unsure if i can do the same thing on cloud computing platforms like amazon aws. I posted my question on their forum and customer support.

ZERO reply. Disappointing.

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  For AWS, you need to use a wildcard A record to point all traffic to *.myplatform.com to your S3 instance's static IP address.  Users with their own domain names would need to point something like yourservice.theirdomain.com to the same IP (or a CNAME pointing to www.myplatform.com).

Then, have your application code serve the appropriate content based on the requested hostname.

Comment: yes you are right it works like that. sorry it took me so long to answer. was busy getting this setup as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Do the same thing using Amazon AWS. You can have people point to different instances of EC2 or you can point your subdomains to the different homepages/locations on a single EC2 instance. AWS has no such restrictions as mentioned by you.